# How can I prevent a sub being overwritten in Perl?

Tags: perl, subroutine, typeglob

I'm working with legacy code and have to `require` a .pl file that defines a sub `foo`. My problem is that in my `main::` namespace there already is another sub `foo`, which is called later in a part of the program I'm currently not dealing with.

The file I require defines `sub foo {}` because obviously it does not want the foo things to happen where it is usually called. In my case, that is bad.

I've tried playing around with the `*foo` glob:

```
*old_foo = *foo;
require 'foo_killer.pl';
*foo = *old_foo;
```

Of course, that doesn't work since I've only created an alias (as brian d foy points out on page 133 of *Mastering Perl*) and thus `*old_foo` will point to the now 'empty' subroutine.

Is there a way to somehow copy what's in `*foo{CODE}` to somewhere else instead of aliasing it? Or is there maybe another approach to solve this?

Comment: Can you redefine your own `foo` within your own namespace (with wrapping it into `package Mine; sub foo {} ... package main;` for example, then call it with this namespace qualifier applied?

Comment: @raina77ow: the first `foo` came from somewhere else entirely. It's not even mine, it just needs to be called. It prints the footer of the webpage, but I don't have influence over it. But if it's replaced by an empty sub the bottom of my webpage is missing, which feels sort of like being caught with your pants down. ;-)

Comment: No, I've talked about namespacing the 'foo' you can alter, not the other one. )

Comment: @raina77ow: Thanks for the idea. That one is outside of my control in yet another `require`d file which is in use in most of the parts of the application. I don't see how I could change that. :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
{
    local *foo;
    require 'foo_killer.pl';
}
```

Comment: This is actually a lot clearer than my own solution. I'll switch to this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out myself. I have to use the `CODE` portion of the typeglob instead of assigning the whole typeglob to another typeglob. That way it seems to make a copy.

```
*old_foo = *foo{CODE};
require 'foo_killer.pl';
*foo = *old_foo{CODE};
```

brian d foy also talks about this in *Mastering Perl* (on page 131f), but doesn't mention the copying part.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest wrapping the evil legacy code into a package once and for all.

```
package Foo;
use strict; 
use warnings;

use Exporter;
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(foo bar $evil $global $variables);

do "foo_killer.pl"
     or die "Failed to load foo_killer.pl: ".($@ || $!);
1;
```

Here I use `do`, because `require` does nothing if the code is required elsewhere. (We had ugly `require "//path/to/code.pl"` because of this!)

This way you can decide whether to load `foo` via `use Foo qw(foo);` or `use Foo qw(bar);`.

**UPDATE:** Oh, and you'd better calculate path to `foo_killer.pl` relatively to `__FILE__` and not load it by absolute path:

```
my $foo_killer = __FILE__; # $LIB/Foo.pm
$foo_killer =~ s,(/+[^/]+),legacy,; # $LIB/legacy
$foo_killer .= "foo_killer.pl"; # $LIB/legacy/foo_killer.pl
# now do $foo_killer;
```

It's up to you (and your team) though.

Comment: Thank you. This certainly is something to think about. I will investigate in this direction.